# Express Gateway get "Cannot get"

Tags: node.js, express, api-gateway

i follow the getting started guide for Express Gateway.

This is the example configuration

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/ip'
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
              changeOrigin: true
```

and if I run npm start and navigate localhost:8080/ip I see the response.

But if i change httpbin url to "localhost:3001" if I navigate localhost:8080/ip the response is "Cannot GET ip/".
Why???

On port 3001 i have a working service that produce response

Comment: any luck with this answer, im facing the same error too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.
  Add path options under
`- action:
   serviceEndpoint: {apiName}
   ignorePath:   false
   prependPath:   true
   stripPath:   true`